# XERO API - BankTransactions not showing LineItems

Tags: postman, xero-api

I am using Postman to test extracting data from Xero Api.

The BankTransactions call bring back right amount of bank transaction records, but the lineitems section is always blank.

While I can confirm that the BankTransaction have been reconciled and assigned to a Contact and Account I dont see this information in any of he records.

[image]

Below you can clearly see that recon have assigned this expense to **Entertainment**.

[image]

Based on the documentation [Xero Bank Transactions](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/banktransactions) the Line Items would contain info on the account the transaction was assigned to.

[image]

Comment: Do any of these conditions apply to your reconciled transaction? `This endpoint does not return payments applied to invoices, expense claims or transfers between bank accounts.`

Comment: I added an additional screenshot that shows the recon account assignment. But from your comment @KeithRusso I can see that would need to ingest data from additional datasets to gain more insight.

Comment: Can you please post the API call with the parameterization you are using? That will help solve this issue instead of just the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the url of the API call, I am assuming the line item object is blank because the page parameter is not included in the URL. In the documentation it states in the description for the page parameter:

> Up to 100 bank transactions will be returned per call, **with line
> items shown for each transaction, when the page parameter is used**
> e.g. page=1

```
https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/BankTransactions?page=1
```

Comment: Yes  I used the standard URL they in the Postman package: https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/BankTransactions ... but will look into the page # option.